# Ensuring single-user per account with flask-login

Tags: python, cookies, flask, flask-login

The way I understand Flask-login is that once authenticated, it sets a cookie containing the user id which gets sent with each request, so that the server can associate a request with a (logged in) user. The user id is pretty much encoded as a function of the user id and some browser settings (user agent, I think).

A few problems arise from this, and maybe someone can comment on them and suggest solutions.

- A client can request content if it pretends to be a logged in user by guessing the user id and using the same cookie encoding funtion.
- Multiple users can use the same user account from two different machines when they share account credentials (I want to restrict this, but I want to allow a user to open multiple tabs of the same session on one machine).

I could implement a server-side mechanism that generates a random secret token upon authentication that gets stored alongside the user record and which will become the session cookie. I could use this to ensure only authenticated users can log in on a single machine (hopefully multiple tabs from one machine are still working). Does flask-login already contain such a method and is this generally an ok idea to cater for my requirements?

Comment: You might want to restrict users to a single session, but I would like to hear me out: please do not. You should see the session as a base layer (anonymous user), then the user account is linked to the session upon login. Temporary state should be associated with the session, not the user account. Many online shops do this already: for example, the cart in each session is independant. To "transfer" a cart, many sites will let you save the cart and re-open it in any session.

Comment: I don't have to maintain any temporary state other than what is encoded in the URL and the authentication session. This doesn't apply to my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing what I suggested in my question. The sequence is that (1) the authentication token will be extracted from the session cookie, (2) the user of this auth token is queries for, (3a) if not found access is prohibited and the login page is show, or (3b) the requested page is returned.

When a user logs in, instead of calling `login_user`, I call

```
def login_user_with_secret_session(user, remember=False, force=False):
    auth_session_token = random.getrandbits(128)
    auth_session_token = '%032x' % auth_session_token
    # store `auth_session_token` in user table
    set_user_auth_session_token(user, auth_session_token)
    return login_user(user, remember=remember, force=force)
```

Another modification was `login_manager.id_attribute = 'get_auth_session_token'` and

```
class User(Base, UserMixin):
    __table__ = user_table

    ...

    def get_auth_session_token(self):
        return self.auth_session_token
```

to return the authentication token for `flask-login` to access.

Answer (score 2):

I have not gone through [Flask-login's source](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/), but as you say it uses the Flask session object, it means that this part of Flask-login is secure since the [session cookie is cryptographically signed to protect against forgery](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#sessions). Flask calls it the "SecureCookie-backed session." The data is not encrypted, but since it is signed, the user may not modify it.

This has some advantages:

- The burden of storing the actual session is shifted to the client. No need to store the session in a database. It is great if you have many anonymous users and need to store non-critical state.
- It is supposed to be secure
- Through the use of browser extensions, or manually, the user can transfer their session from a device to another

but also some disadvantages:

- Additional data is transferred back and forth
- If user clears the cache, they lose all session data. Same if their device crashes.
- Given enough time, since an attacker has access to multiple messages and their signature, it could theoretically guess your secret key through bruteforcing.

Make sure your SECRET_KEY is strong enough.

Comment: Oh that's good news. So the secure cookie backed session alleviates at least my first point (one can still copy the encoded cookie and use it on another machine). The disadvantages are not a problem; (1) footprint is minimal, (2) this is expected behaviour  and the user can be expected to log in again, (3) this also goes for any other encryption method.